# 2 Column Array Rank with tiebreaker and Save Python numpy

Tags: python, arrays, django, numpy, scipy

I need to be able to rank an array based on a single column and then again with using a second column as basically a tie breaker and then save those two ranks into the database

Array:

```
array = np.array(
    [(70,3,100),
     (72,3,101),
     (70,2,102)], dtype=[
                  ('score','int8'),
                  ('tiebreaker','int8'),
                  ('row_id','int8')])
array['score'] = array([70, 72, 70], dtype=int8)
```

First Rank using only the 'score' column would return

```
(1,3,1)
```

Then the second Rank rankings using 'score' and 'tiebreaker' columns

```
(2,3,1)
```

Then I want to save those two ranks to the database for example:

```
result1 = Result.objects.get(id=array[0]['row_id'])
result1.relative_rank = 1
result1.absolute_rank = 2
results.save()
```

Comment: `array.sort(order=['score', 'tiebreaker'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.stats.rankdata`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html), as follows:

```
In [10]: a
Out[10]: 
array([(70, 3, 100), (72, 3, 101), (70, 2, 102)], 
      dtype=[('score', 'i1'), ('tiebreaker', 'i1'), ('row_id', 'i1')])

In [11]: from scipy.stats import rankdata
```

First rank:

```
In [12]: rankdata(a['score'], method='min').astype(int)
Out[12]: array([1, 3, 1])
```

Second rank:

```
In [13]: rankdata(256*a['score'] + a['tiebreaker'], method='min').astype(int)
Out[13]: array([2, 3, 1])
```

The value used in the second rank (`256*a['score'] + a['tiebreaker']`) relies on the data having type `int8`.

Check the docstring to see if a different `method` would be more appropriate for the second rank.  If you know there will be no ties in the second rank, the method doesn't matter.

Comment: How can you push the rank array into another column on that results array?  a['rank_1'] = array([1,3,1])

Comment: You could create the `rank_1` field along with the original fields when the array is created (filled with dummy values, e.g. 0).  E.g. `a = array([(70, 3, 100, 0), ...], dtype=[('score', 'int8'), ..., ('rank_1', int)])`.